# O que é herança diferencial?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Eu estava lendo [este artigo no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new) e me deparei com o termo *differential inheritance*.

O que, exatamente, é herança diferencial?

É possível termos um exemplo mínimo, preferencialmente em JavaScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do bfavaretto.

Em linguagens como Java e .NET, as instâncias são todas bastardas**, pois somente os tipos têm direito a herança.

Já em Javascript, todo mundo pode "herdar" de todo mundo. Todo objeto em Javascript possui um protótipo. O protótipo diz a um objeto que propriedades ele possui via herança. E a linguagem permite que você faça atrocidades bem legais como essa:

```
var foo = {}; // esse objeto herda de Object.
foo.prototype = Array.prototype; // E agora ele tem um protótipo comum com o Array :D
```

Você pode levar isso um passo adiante.

```
var bar = {nome: "John Doe", idade: 21};
foo.prototype = bar; //sim, isso é permitido.
```

Dá pra levar mais adiante...

```
var bar = {nome: "John Doe", idade: 21};
var foo = function () {};
foo.prototype = bar;
var ni = new foo(); // sério, veja as propriedades de ni.
```

Temos um processo de adoção aqui, pois agora o "pai" de `foo` passa a ser `bar`. O pai do objeto passa a ser outro objeto, e não um tipo.

Sim, essas relações familiares modernas, com laços tão tênues, são realmente bem complexas...

Falando sério agora: essa história de herdar de um objeto e não de um tipo é que se chama herança diferencial. Isso dá muito poder ao programador - você pode **definir as heranças dinamicamente e em tempo de execução**, e com **mais flexibilidade do que no modelo OO "tradicional"**. Mas esses poderes trazem grandes responsabilidades, especialmente em um mundo onde a única tipagem segura é a [tipagem de pato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

** Isso NÃO é um termo técnico ;)

Answer (score 8):

Tradução livre de [artigo da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_inheritance) (tão magro que a gente até desconfia):

> Herança diferencial é um modelo comum de herança utilizado em linguagens de programação baseadas em protótipos, como JavaScript, Io e NewtonScript. Opera segundo o princípio que muitos objetos derivam de outros objetos mais genéricos, e só diferem deles em poucos detalhes; geralmente o objeto derivado mantém internamente uma lista de ponteiros para os mais genéricos.

[Nesta pergunta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771734/what-is-differential-inheritance-in-javascript), dizem que herança diferencial é um sinônimo de herança prototípica, mas que seu uso em relação a JavaScript é para enfatizar o padrão "puro" em que se usa `Object.create` para herdar diretamente de outro objeto, em vez do `new`, que é um artifício que o JavaScript possui para ficar mais parecido com as linguagens baseadas em classes (aliás, no ES6 teremos até a *keyword* `class`, mas internamente tudo continuará funcionando da mesma maneira, a herança continuará prototípica).