# Confuso sobre forma correta de Herança em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, herança, protótipo

Estou estudando formas de aplicar Orientação a Objeto em JavaScript. Percebi que existem várias maneiras de fazer Herança em JavaScript. Fiz esse que achei simples e funcionou. Mas ela realmente está dentro dos padrões? está correta?

Segue o Código:

```
    function humano(){
        var nome;
        this.pensar = function(){
            return "Estou pensando";
        }

    }

    function animal(){
        this.comer = function(){
            return "Vou COMER!";
        }
    }


    humano.prototype = new animal();

    var pablo = new humano();
    pablo.nome = "Pablo";

    console.log(pablo.pensar());
    console.log(pablo.comer());
    console.log("Meu nome é " + pablo.nome);
```

Estudando mais, agora cheguei no seguinte código para Herança, essa seria uma forma avançada de herança em JavaScript? (obs.: As propriedades extras criadas foram para testar a passagem das propriedades por herança)

```
    var obj = {};
    var coisa = {
        nome: 'Rafael',
        idade: '35'
    };

    obj.y = 55;

    Object.defineProperty(obj,'x',{value: 1, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: true});

    Object.defineProperty(obj,'x',{get: function(){ return obj.y}});

    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,"extend",{
        writable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        value: function(o){

            var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o);

            for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ){
                if(names[i] in this) continue;

                var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o,names[i]);

                Object.defineProperty(this,names[i],desc);
            }
        }
    })

    obj.extend(coisa);
    coisa.extend(obj);
```

Qual a melhor maneira? Obrigado

Comment: Não existe forma "correta". Existe a mais apropriada para cada caso. Fazer herança ao determinar que o protótipo de uma função seja um objeto é comum e não há nada de errado com isso. Se resolveu o problema para o seu exemplo de forma simples, então é válido.

Comment: Só mais uma coisa. A variável `nome` na função `humano` é perdida para sempre depois que a função é executada. Ela não faz parte do protótipo de humano, nem de um *closure*, e nem do objeto retornado. Quando você chama seu humano de Pablo, você cria uma nova propriedade no objeto. Então pode descartar esse `var nome` sem problemas.

Comment: Procure [não ter pressa para aceitar uma resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/494/215). Eu estava há uns 10 minutos escrevendo uma bem completa, mas acho que nem vou postar mais... :P

Comment: Estamos aqui para que nossas repostas sejam aceitas? Ou para ajudar a comunidade? Mas mesmo assim sou grato pelo seus 10 minutos @mgibsonbr. Muito Obrigado

Comment: @MichaelAlves Existe material bom aqui mesmo no SOpt explicando a herança em JavaScript. Eu estava a compilar e contextualizar a seu caso particular. Mas se você está satisfeito com o que recebeu até agora, não faz sentido eu continuar. Deixo esse link como referência caso você queira saber mais: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/215 P.S. Este também é bom: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30718/215

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu gostaria de ver sua resposta! Embora concorde que a pessoa deva esperar um pouco pra aceitar uma resposta kkkk

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu também fiquei curioso quanto ao que você ia dizer... Por acaso teria a ver com o que coloquei na minha resposta?

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu tb fiquei curioso :P Se ainda estiver na cache coloca. As tuas respostas costuma valer a pena ler!

Comment: A questão não é a minha resposta, estava apenas indicando ao AP que ele poderia de um modo geral receber respostas melhores se esperasse mais para aceitar uma (depende do tipo de pergunta). Nem tanto pela possibilidade da resposta ser aceita, mas porque é um indicio que o AP está satisfeito e pode nem voltar mais àquela pergunta. Quanto ao que eu ia escrever, não é nada de mais, se fosse teria ido em frente e postado de qualquer forma... :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Sua resposta cobre em parte o que eu ia dizer (gasta-se menos memória colocando os métodos no protótipo do que na própria instância, se são muitos os objetos), e a outra parte refere-se ao uso do `var nome` no construtor - que não está *incorreto* ([há casos de uso pra isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9938/215)) mas teria um efeito diferente do que o pretendido. No mais era uma explicação de como a cadeia de protótipos funciona - coisa que pode ser encontrada nas outras perguntas referenciadas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como está a usar é correto.

Talvez seja interessante melhorar alguns detalhes.
Por exemplo pode fazer o nome ser propriedade interna e assim fazer parte do protótipo de humanos:

```
function humano(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
```

Assim evita fazer

```
var pablo = new humano();
pablo.nome = "Pablo";  // aqui a propriedade "nome" é local ao pablo, e não a outros humanos
```

e pode fazer somente

```
var pablo = new humano('Pablo');
```

O mesmo se aplica ao que ele está a comer, por exemplo.
Passando comida como argumento aqui:

```
function animal(comida) {
    this.comer = function () {
        return "Vou comer " + comida + "!";
    }
}
```

então `pablo.comer()` vai dar resposta mais interessante.

Poderia ainda fazer de `this.comida` um método que guarda o que ele come. Por exemplo:

```
function animal() {
    this comida = function (comida){
        this.comer = 'Eu gosto de ' + comida;
    }
}
```

Dê uma olhada ao exemplo em baixo:

```js
function Humano(nome) {
    this.nome = nome; 
    this.pensar = function () {
        return "Estou pensando";
    }

}

function Animal() {
        this.comida = function (comida){
            this.comer = 'Eu gosto de ' + comida;
        }
}

Humano.prototype = new Animal();
var pablo = new Humano('Pablo');
var coelho = new Animal();

pablo.comida('Lasanha');
coelho.comida('Cenoura');

console.log(pablo.pensar());
console.log(pablo.comer);
console.log("Meu nome é " + pablo.nome);
console.log(coelho.comer);
```

Por norma usamos letra grande no inicio do nome de uma Classe. Assim deveria ser `Humano` e `Animal`.

Comment: A sua resposta, na minha opinião é muito boa, só mudaria uma coisa: o seu objeto animal não precisa ser inicializado com uma "comida", pra mim isso não faz sentido. Comida deveria ser uma parâmetro da função comerDa forma como você fez, o seu animal sempre comeria lasanha... rsrsr

Comment: Reinaldo tens razão, os Coelhos podem não gostar de Lasanha :) Foi um exemplo e pode ser melhorado. Vou melhorar obrigado. (e podes apagar esta resposta entretanto)

Comment: @ReinaldoOliveira Converti sua resposta para comentário. Sinto muito pela perda dos pontos, mas pelo visto você tem conhecimento suficiente para recuperá-los bem rápido postando outras respostas ;)

Answer (score 7):

Como [disse o Renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42122/confuso-sobre-forma-correta-de-heran%c3%a7a-em-javascript/42143#comment83279_42122), não existe forma "correta", e essa solução funciona bem no seu exemplo. Mas eu gostaria de mostrar uma outra que resolve um problema comum da sua solução. O problema ocorre quando o construtor da "superclasse" <sup>1</sup> espera um parâmetro obrigatório. Por exemplo:

```
function Animal(caracteristicas) {
    this.classe = caracteristicas.classe
    this.patas = caracteristicas.patas
}
Animal.prototype = {
    comer: function() {}
}

function Humano() {
    // ...
}
Humano.prototype = new Animal({
    classe: "mamíferos",
    patas: 2
});
```

No exemplo acima, para ciar um objeto `Humano.prototype` é preciso passar os parâmetros ao construtor como objeto. Vai dar erro se você não passar, porque o código do construtor tenta acessar as propriedades desse objeto. Claro que é possível tratar esse erro dentro do construtor `Animal`, mas não é uma solução genérica.

Existe uma outra maneira de se criar um objeto que tenha o método `comer` (portanto, um objeto que herde de `Animal.prototype`) sem invocar o construtor, evitando o problema:

```
function Humano() {
    // ...
}
Humano.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
var pessoa = new Humano();
pessoa.comer(); // funciona!
```

Essa é uma maneira mais flexível de se trabalhar a herança, pois não depende da invocação dos construtores. Se a sua cadeia de protótipo é longa e vários construtores possuem parâmetros que podem causar o problema que mencionei, considere utilizar este método.

---

<sup>(1) Não se trata exatamente de superclasse em JS, já que a linguagem usa [herança prototípica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript).</sup>