# Como fazer herança múltipla em javascript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

Tenho visto várias formas de se fazer **herança** em javascript, mas não sei como fazer **herança-múltipla** vou demostrar um exemplo do problema:

```
        function Transporte() { 
            var nome; 
            this.getNome = function () { 
                return nome; 
            }; 
            this.setNome = function (value) { 
                nome = value; 
            }; 
        } 

        function Motor() { 
            var motor; 
            this.getMotor = function () { return motor; }; 
            this.setMotor = function (value) { motor = value; }; 
        } 

        function Propulsor() { 
            var propulsor; 
            this.getTurbina = function () { return propulsor; }; 
            this.setTurbina = function (value) { propulsor = value; }; 
        } 

        Motor.prototype = new Transporte(); 
        Propulsor.prototype = new Transporte();

        function document_OnLoad() { 
            var carro = new Motor(); 
            var aviao = new Propulsor(); 

            carro.setMotor('4.1');
            carro.setNome('opala');

            aviao.setTurbina('123');
            aviao.setNome('Teco-Teco');

            console.log(carro.getMotor()+'  '+carro.getNome());
            console.log(aviao.getTurbina()+'  '+aviao.getNome());
        }
```

Desta forma que foi escrito o código fonte, eu tenho uma herança simples:

- Carro Instancia Motor e herdara de Transporte
- Avião Instancia Propulsor e herdara de Transporte

A minha dúvida é:

**<s>Tem como usar o prototype para herdar Motor,Propulsor e Transporte?</s>**

**Tem como usar algum recurso para herdar Motor,Propulsor e Transporte?**

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada no conceito de [***mixins***](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27179/215), pois JavaScript não suporta herança múltipla diretamente (i.e. a [cadeia de protótipos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/215) forma uma árvore simples, em que cada objeto possui somente um único protótipo, não pode ter mais). P.S. Mais informações sobre o funcionamento de [protótipos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/215) e [herança](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42122/215) em JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei uma técnica que resolve a questão vou postar a biblioteca e dar os créditos ao Sr. **Nicholas C. Zakas** que disponibilizou o código em sua página.

http://www.nczonline.net/downloads/zInherit1.0.zip

Irei exemplificar o seu uso conforme abaixo:

```js
 /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * JavaScript zInherit Library
  * Version 1.0
  * by Nicholas C. Zakas, http://www.nczonline.net/
  * Copyright (c) 2004-2005 Nicholas C. Zakas. All Rights Reserved.
  *
  * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
  * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
  * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
  * (at your option) any later version.
  *
  * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  * GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
  *
  * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
  * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
  * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307 USA
  *------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */
  
 /**
  * Inherits properties and methods from the given class.
  * @scope public
  * @param fnClass The constructor function to inherit from.
  */
 Object.prototype.inheritFrom = function (fnClass /*: Function */) /*:void*/ {

  /**
   * Inherits all classes going up the inheritance chain recursively.
   * @param fnClass The class to inherit from.
   * @param arrClasses The array of classes to build up.
   * @scope private
   */
  function inheritClasses(fnClass /*:Function*/, 
        arrClasses /*:Array*/) /*:void*/ {
   
   arrClasses.push(fnClass);

   if (typeof fnClass.__superclasses__ == "object") {
    for (var i=0; i < fnClass.__superclasses__.length; i++){
     inheritClasses(fnClass.__superclasses__[i], arrClasses);
    }
   }
  }
  
  if (typeof this.constructor.__superclasses__ == "undefined") {
   this.constructor.__superclasses__ = new Array();
  }
  
  inheritClasses(fnClass, this.constructor.__superclasses__);
  
  for (prop in fnClass.prototype) {
   if (typeof fnClass.prototype[prop] == "function") {
    this[prop] = fnClass.prototype[prop];
   }
  }
 };

 /**
  * Determines if the given object is an instance of a given class.
  * This method is necessary because using {@link #inheritFrom} renders
  * the JavaScript <code>instanceof</code> operator useless.
  * @param fnClass The constructor function to test.
  * @return True if the object is an instance of the class, false if not.
  * @scope public
  */
 Object.prototype.instanceOf = function (fnClass /*:Function*/) /*: boolean */ {

  if (this.constructor == fnClass) {
   return true;
  } else if (typeof this.constructor.__superclasses__ == "object") {
   for (var i=0; i < this.constructor.__superclasses__.length; i++) {
    if (this.constructor.__superclasses__[i] == fnClass) {
     return true;
    }
   }
   return false;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 };

function Transporte() { 
           var nome; 
           this.getNome = function () { return nome; }; 
           this.setNome = function (value) { nome = value; };             
    } 

    function Motor() { 
        var motor; 
        this.getMotor = function () { return motor; }; 
        this.setMotor = function (value) { motor = value; }; 
    } 

    function Propulsor() { 
        var propulsor; 
        this.getTurbina = function () { return propulsor; }; 
        this.setTurbina = function (value) { propulsor = value; }; 
    } 

    function CarroVoador(){
        Motor.apply(this);
        Propulsor.apply(this);
        Transporte.apply(this);
    }

    Motor.prototype = new Transporte(); 
    Propulsor.prototype = new Transporte();

    CarroVoador.prototype.inheritFrom(Motor);
    CarroVoador.prototype.inheritFrom(Propulsor);
    CarroVoador.prototype.inheritFrom(Transporte);

    var carro = new Motor(); 
    var aviao = new Propulsor(); 
    var carroVoador = new CarroVoador();
    carro.setMotor('4.1');
    carro.setNome('opala');

    aviao.setTurbina('123');
    aviao.setNome('Teco-Teco');

    carroVoador.setNome('supercarro');
    carroVoador.setTurbina('123');
    carroVoador.setMotor('4.1');

    $('body').append('motor: '+carro.getMotor()+' nome:'+carro.getNome());
    $('body').append('<br/>').append('propulsor: '+aviao.getTurbina()+' nome: '+aviao.getNome());
    $('body').append('<br/>').append('motor: '+carroVoador.getMotor()+' propulsor: '+carroVoador.getTurbina()+' nome: '+carroVoador.getNome());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```